# MKMapView - make mine look like Apple's [slow rotation and Title header]

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

My iPhone app has a table view of  my company's locations. When the user touches a location the app opens a UIView with the some details of the location (name, phone, address, etc.)

I made it so if the user touches the address then I pass the location data to the Maps app. In the Maps App I get this:

[image]

And if I touch the right arrow ">" I get this

[image]

This is awesome. I am adding a MKMapView into my UIView so the user can see the satellite map at the top of the screen. So far everything works great, except for two things.

I have added a UILabel to the MKMapView but I would like to use the same font and style as Apple, which I think is Myriad and the style is extrude, but I am not sure. So one question is what is the font and style, and in general how could I determine something like that.

Second, you cannot see it in the picture but the map rotates very slowly. It is a very nice effect.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.!

Bryan